# Using Lua for working with excel

Tags: excel, lua

I am planning to learn Lua for my desktop scripting needs. I want to know if there is any documentation available and also if there are all the things needed in the Standard Lib.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should check out Lua for Windows -- a 'batteries included environment' for the Lua scripting language on Windows

http://luaforwindows.luaforge.net/

It includes the LuaCOM library, from which you can access the Excel COM object.

Try looking at the LuaCOM documentation, there are some Excel examples in that:

http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~rcerq/luacom/pub/1.3/luacom-htmldoc/

I've only ever used this for very simplistic things. Here is a sample to get you started:

```
-- test.lua
require('luacom')
excel = luacom.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = true
wb = excel.Workbooks:Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

for i=1, 20 do
    ws.Cells(i,1).Value2 = i
end
```

Comment: Thanks uroc for your quick response. If possible, please let me know of any beginner tutorial or atleast some sample code for using COM programming via Lua. :)

Answer (score 3):

More complex code example for lua working with excel:

```
require "luacom"

excel = luacom.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

local book  = excel.Workbooks:Add()
local sheet = book.Worksheets(1)

excel.Visible = true

for row=1, 30 do
  for col=1, 30 do
    sheet.Cells(row, col).Value2 = math.floor(math.random() * 100)
  end
end


local range = sheet:Range("A1")

for row=1, 30 do
  for col=1, 30 do
    local v = sheet.Cells(row, col).Value2

    if v > 50 then
        local cell = range:Offset(row-1, col-1)

        cell:Select()
        excel.Selection.Interior.Color = 65535
    end
  end
end

excel.DisplayAlerts = false
excel:Quit()
excel = nil
```

Another example, could add a graph chart.

```
require "luacom"

excel = luacom.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

local book  = excel.Workbooks:Add()
local sheet = book.Worksheets(1)

excel.Visible = true

for row=1, 30 do
  sheet.Cells(row, 1).Value2 = math.floor(math.random() * 100)
end

local chart = excel.Charts:Add()
chart.ChartType = 4 — xlLine

local range = sheet:Range("A1:A30")
chart:SetSourceData(range)
```

Comment: A quick suggestion: fragments of code will look better if you format them as code (use the little "101 010" button).